# LDAP Query to get all objects that are of objectCategory user or decend from user

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to find a objectCategory query that will return all the "users" in my active directory.

I thought this would be as simple as `(objectCategory=user)`.  And while that does return the bulk of my users, it does not return them all.

I have some Group Managed Service Accounts (gMSA) in my Active Directory.  They have the objectCategory of *msDS-GroupManagedServiceAccount*.  When I look up [*msDS-GroupManagedServiceAccount*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/c-msds-managedserviceaccount) it indicates that it has fields derived from *user*.

That leads me to to believe that *msDS-GroupManagedServiceAccount* is a subclass of *user*.  Which leads to my question:

**Is there a way to indicate that I want all objects that are of objectCategory *user* AND all objects that descend from objectCategory *user*?**

Comment: Can you do it with an `objectClass` match? That would work, as all parent classes are present too.

Answer (score 1):

Search by `objectClass` instead of `objectCategory`:

```
(objectClass=user)
```

The [`objectClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-objectclass) attribute started being indexed in Windows Server 2008, so as long as you're running 2008+, it will be just as fast as searching by `objectCategory`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer to your bolded question, but a workaround for for your particular case would be to use an *or* expression.

`(|(objectCategory=person)(objectCategory=msDS-GroupManagedServiceAccount))`